# Change Link href from .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change url used in href from .htaccess. As I am working in a existing project so I don't want to change the href from 46 files. Is there any way? For instance the code below is in the html file.

```
<link href="http://localhost/example.com/UK/styles/style.css">
```

I want to change it to `http://localhost/example.com/styles/style.css` from .htaccess

Here, my absolute domain is `http://localhost/example.com`
And my .htaccess is in the document root

Comment: What is your document root? What is the absolute URL? In your URL/href it looks like `localhost` is a subdirectory?

Comment: ... and in which directory is your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Localhost/example.com is my absolute url. Basically, I changed the base url from "localhost/example.com/" to "localhost/example.com/UK/". Now all the hrefs are changed into localhost/example.com/uk/styles....  Basically, it's searching for the directory "UK", but there is no directory with the name "UK".. My .htaccess file is in the root directory

Comment: "`Localhost/example.com` is my absolute url" - But `Localhost/example.com` is not an "absolute URL". `http://localhost/example.com` would be an absolute URL - is that what you mean? Or something else? `localhost/example.com` is a _relative_ URL, so would result in an absolute URL of the form `http://<hostname>/localhost/example.com/...` if the request originated from the document root. From your example, `localhost` looks like a subdirectory, not a _hostname_ (which is unusual, but not impossible) - please clarify.

Comment: Sorry I described it in a wrong way, 
 `http://localhost/example.com` is my absolute url

Comment: How did you get on with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` doesn't actually "change url used in href", but it allows you to internally rewrite a request from `/example.com/UK/styles/styles.css` to `/example.com/styles/styles.css`. The user still sees `/UK` in the URL, the URL is unchanged, but the file that receives the request is.

For example, at the top of the `.htaccess` file in the "document root". (ie. at `http://localhost/.htaccess`) you can do something like the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(example\.com)/UK/(styles/style.css)$ $1/$2 [L]
```

For a more general "any URL" solution:

```
RewriteRule ^(example\.com)/UK/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
```

`$1` and `$2` are backreferences to the captured subpatterns in the preceding `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule